rehype-slug is not adding ids to headings
I am in the process of implementing a MDX-powered blog in my Next.js app. In my blog, I am using two rehype plugins: rehype-slug and rehype-autolink-headings to add links from headings back to themselves, but the problem is rehype-slug is not adding ids to headings.
I have installed rehype-slug:

I have added rehypeSlug to the rehypePlugins array. Here is my next-config.mjs file:
import createMDX from '@next/mdx'
import remarkFrontmatter from 'remark-frontmatter'
import rehypeSlug from 'rehype-slug'
import rehypeAutolinkHeadings from 'rehype-autolink-headings'

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  pageExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'mdx', 'ts', 'tsx'],
}

const withMDX = createMDX({
  options: {
    remarkPlugins: [remarkFrontmatter],
    rehypePlugins: [
      rehypeSlug,
      [
        rehypeAutolinkHeadings,
        {
          behavior: 'append',
          properties: {
            className: ['anchor-link'],
            title: 'Permalink to this heading',
          },
          content: {
            type: 'element',
            tagName: 'span',
            properties: { className: ['anchor-icon'] },
            children: [{ type: 'text', value: '#' }],
          },
        },
      ],
    ],
  },
})

export default withMDX(nextConfig)

Here is a sample blog post:

Note that Second heading is a H2 header. If I inspect it in developer tools, I see that it does not have any ID (as shown below):

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing any configuration?

Although not obvious from what you posted, I had a similar issue that landed me on your question.
My guess is that you have set up custom elements that is mapping to native HTML in mdx-components file
E.g
h2: ({ children }) => <h2 className="text-gray-900 ">{children}</h2>,

You might want to update that to:
    h2: ({ id, children }) => (
      <h2 id={id} className="text-2xl text-gray-900 font-bold mt-8">
        {children}
      </h2>
    ),

The issue is with id not being passed to the custom Element. An alternative is to use a spread operator to spread all the props
    h2: (props) => (
      <h2 className="text-2xl text-gray-900 font-bold mt-8" {...props}>
        {props.children}
      </h2>
    ),

